# Change model's table name runtime

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, sequelize.js, database-partitioning

I am using Sequelize.js and need to save historical data till specific year and want to separate my tables by year's prefix
for example prices_2010, prices_2011 e.g.
I can create so

```
tableName:"company_historical_" + new Date().getFullYear();
```

for current years table and it will use this name for table, but what if I want to store or query data of 2015 year and want to use models instead of raw queries.
So how can I change table of use runtime.
something like `changeTable()` method sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store any kind of information like years as table names since its data. You should store them as separate table entries, as actual usable data.

Change `company_historical_<year>` to just `company_historical` and create a new table called `company_historical_years` which just has all the possible years the **Company Historical** entries can have.

Then create a relationship between the **Company Historical** entry and the related **Company Historcal Years** entry.

So something like:

```
var CompanyHistoricalYears = sequelize.define('company_historical_years', {
    year: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            CompanyHistoricalYears.hasMany(models.CompanyHistorical);
        }
    }
};


var CompanyHistorical = sequelize.define('company_historical', {
    ...
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            CompanyHistorical.belongsTo(models.CompanyHistoricalYears);
        }
    }
};
```

and then you can query it with:

```
CompanyHistoricalYears.findOne({
    where: {
        year: 2011, // or you can use "new Date().getFullYear()"
    },
    include: [CompanyHistorical]
});
```

this will give you a single `CompanyHistoricalYears` entry and all the `CompanyHistorical` entries that are within that year.

If non of this makes sense then feel free to comment with any questions.