# Sequelize - one model relates to multiple tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have multiple tables named "register_yyyymmdd"(horizon sharding) to save logs in mysql.I define a Model like:

**Register.js**

```
const Register = sequelize.connection.define('Register', 
{
    ip        : Sequelize.STRING,
    log_time  : Sequelize.INTEGER
},
{
    tableName : 'register_20180516'
};
module.exports = Register;
```

When I trying to save data like:

```
Register.build(data).save();
```

How can I specify the table name(base on date) which I want to insert? For example, it may insert data in to table `register_20180517` when today is May 17 2018.

Comment: May be you should look at alternative db design. Storing year in the table name might now be the best idea. Looks at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307333/change-models-table-name-runtime

Comment: According to the post, I rename table to `register` and create a new table named `register_years`. Storing data into  table `register` from now on.  But I have to create a timer to transfer the data which in table `register`  to `register_years`  at the end of this year. That might be not a good idea.